# IE download incomplete even though it claims success

Tags: php, download

I'm serving a zipped up file for my clients to download and it works in every OS/Browser except for IE.

The zipped file is 550 MB. When I use IE 8 the file downloads between 50 - 70 MBs and then claims that the download is complete even though the original file is 550 MB.

I'm wondering if I missing some required headers or something.  Here is the php code I'm using to serve the file.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$dnfilename");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($ZIPFILE));
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile("$ZIPFILE");   
?>
```

Comment: `it works in every OS/Browser except for IE.` Big surprise :). Can others replcate the issues, or are you the only one who has tested this?

Comment: This has happened to several of my clients, all running IE.

Comment: @ctown4life - I tried your code with IE 9 and it works fine for me. Downloaded a 1.5GB file without any problem. Is the problem just with IE 8?

Comment: Looks like I may have jumped the gun by blaming IE. I just tried it in Chrome on Win XP and it failed at 112 MBs. I then tried the same thing in Chrome on both Mac & Linux and it worked fine.  I'm not sure what is going on. @KristerAndersson thanks for the test, I do not have IE 9 available to test on.

Comment: One difference to consider is that my Mac & Linux are on faster connections (downloading around 2 MBs sec) and my Windows machine is a much slower connection (downloads around 200 KBs sec).

Comment: I am having a similar issue. My site is serving an 1GB file to customer. But IE claims the download is SUCCESSFULLY finished when only around 800M is downloaded. This happens with IE9 and I am using IIS7 + ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but the following works for me on IE8 - 9, Chrome and Firefox using a 1.5GB zip file.

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$dnfilename."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($ZIPFILE));
readfile($ZIPFILE);
```

Have a look at this article: [HTTP Headers for ZIP File Downloads](http://perishablepress.com/press/2010/11/17/http-headers-file-downloads/)

Comment: This is still a problem for me even though I properly set the headers.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem in IE7 and IE8. IE9 and other browsers worked just fine. If you change your Content-Type header, it works.

Change

```
header("Content-type: application/zip");
```

to

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
```